# NSOutlineView: remove disclosure triangle and indent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I'm using NSOutlineView for a project, and can't seem to figure out two things:

- How to remove the disclosure triangle for tree nodes. Apps like iTunes seem to be able to do this:

[image]

Is there some sort of NSOutlineView Delegate method that is used for this? Or does it require a  subclass?

- How to disable indenting for items. I've tried using **setIndentationPerLevel:** and setting it to 0, as well as changing the column indent to 0 in Interface Builder, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've run into the right person here. I've had to grapple with this just a week ago.

**Removing the disclosure triangle**: implement the `frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:` method in your `NSOutlineView` subclass and return `NSZeroRect` (only if you want to hide that particular row's triangle, of course.)

```
- (NSRect)frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:(NSInteger)row {
    return NSZeroRect;
}
```

**Disable indenting**: the outline view's standard layout reserves space at the far left to draw the triangles in, in case the item is expandable. But you can override that for individual items by specifying a different drawing frame. You also do that in your subclass, by responding to this message:

```
- (NSRect)frameOfCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSRect superFrame = [super frameOfCellAtColumn:column row:row];


    if ((column == 0) /* && isGroupRow */) {
        return NSMakeRect(0, superFrame.origin.y, [self bounds].size.width, superFrame.size.height);
    }
    return superFrame;
}
```

Comment: You can affect the indentation without subclassing the outlineView by setting indentationMarkerFollowsCell to false.

Answer (score 38):

For future reference, the cleanest and simplest way to hide the disclosure triangle in expandable [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) items is by implementing the [outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSOutlineViewDelegate/outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:) method of the [NSOutlineViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol in your delegate:

```
-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:(id)item
{
    // replace this with your logic to determine whether the
    // disclosure triangle should be hidden for a particular item
    return [item hidesDisclosureTriangle];
}
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I am no longer able to (programmatically) collapse these items. Is this a mistake on my side?

Comment: This delegate method doesn't seem to be called for view-based outlineviews.  In that case I found that setting indentation to 0 in IB had the desired effect

Answer (score 10):

I had to combine the two approaches above because `outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:` alone does not remove the space reserved for the disclosure triangles (it does remove the triangles themselves).

Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:(id)item {
    return NO;
}
```

Subclass of NSOutlineView:

```
@implementation ExpandedOutlineView

#define kOutlineCellWidth 11
#define kOutlineMinLeftMargin 6

- (NSRect)frameOfCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSRect superFrame = [super frameOfCellAtColumn:column row:row];
    if (column == 0) {
        // expand by kOutlineCellWidth to the left to cancel the indent
        CGFloat adjustment = kOutlineCellWidth;

        // ...but be extra defensive because we have no clue what is going on here
        if (superFrame.origin.x - adjustment < kOutlineMinLeftMargin) {
            NSLog(@"%@ adjustment amount is incorrect: adjustment = %f, superFrame = %@, kOutlineMinLeftMargin = %f", NSStringFromClass([self class]), (float)adjustment, NSStringFromRect(superFrame), (float)kOutlineMinLeftMargin);
            adjustment = MAX(0, superFrame.origin.x - kOutlineMinLeftMargin);
        }

        return NSMakeRect(superFrame.origin.x - adjustment, superFrame.origin.y, superFrame.size.width + adjustment, superFrame.size.height);
    }
    return superFrame;
}

@end
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of NSOutlineView with no top-level indentation]

Comment: Note that column 0 may not be the outline column. Imagine left-hand checkboxes for inclusion (best place for them so they're all aligned the same). It's better to ask the outline view for its -outlineTableColumn rather than assuming it's column 0.

Comment: In that case , use unique identifier for the column.

Comment: I'm agree for frameOfCellAtColumn:row:
But returning NO to outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem: will prevent to collapse the item thereafter

Comment: This works nicely as long as the `NSOutlineView` doesn't have `usesAutomaticRowHeights` turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PXSourceList](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList).  It's the style you're looking for with a very nice api.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it does indeed have a very nice API. I'm using that in combination with Marcel's tip to remove the indent to achieve what I wanted :-)

Comment: If you use PXSourceList you can achieve that style by returning `YES` to the `PXSourceListDelegate` message `-sourceList:isGroupAlwaysExpanded:` for the group you want displayed like that.

Comment: Very nice reference. PXSourceList looks like a huge time-saver. Thanks, Dave and especially Alex. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the intention per level is by overwriting `indentationPerLevel` of NSOutlineView.

```
class NoIndentOutlineView: NSOutlineView {
    override var indentationPerLevel: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0;
        }
        set {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

This will make sure children have the same indention as the parents.

Answer (score 0):

This is in regards to hiding the disclosure button. If you're looking to globally hide it on expandable items, one can do this:

```
extension NSOutlineView {
    override open func makeView(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier, owner: Any?) -> NSView? {
        if identifier == NSOutlineView.disclosureButtonIdentifier {
            return nil
        } else {
            return super.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: owner)
        }
    }
}
```

Else you can subclass `NSOutlineView` and override the `makeView` function.

I know the q is for obj-c. I just had to work through this and my project is swift.

Answer (score 0):

Above are great answers for what the OP asked about - removing the disclosure triangle and the space it occupies. To achieve 'list without expansion and all items on the same level', which is the *effect* they're after, all you need to do is put a number of top level items into the array used as data source and implement

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried this in Swift. It just works. I don't know whether it is a proper way. There should be equivalent in Obj-C:

```
extension NSTableRowView {
    override open func layout() {
        super.layout()
        if let cell = subviews.first as? NSTableCellView, cell.objectValue is <YourHeaderCellClass> {
            subviews.first?.setFrameOrigin(NSZeroPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure you return YourHeaderCellClass item in datasource method.

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any
```

Comment: Sorry to downvote your answer, but this is a very dangerous way of doing it. You are making assumptions about the index of subviews in their arrays, which is an implementation detail beyond your control. As in all things Cocoa, it is best to not fight the framework but first search for a delegate method you can override (see other answers above).